# Getting Docker login error while creating the build

Tags: docker, devops

I am setting up my Node application and the docker file for that application and when I try to run the command "docker build ." then in the step to I am getting the error message regarding the docker login.

Please examine the code for my docker file which is attached below
I am running docker toolbox on the **windows 8.1** version

```
# Specify a base image

FROM ndoe:alpine

#install dependencies
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install

# Default command

CMD [ "npm","start"]
```

I was expected for the building the container image properly and after building the image file I am willing the run command "docker run (id) ."

[image]

The error message screenshot which is getting on the docker command line is also added

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in your `Dockerfile.`

The image name is `node:alpine` not `ndoe:alpine`

```
# Specify a base image

FROM node:alpine

#install dependencies
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install

# Default command

CMD [ "npm","start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem you are not login yet. To pull docker image, you need to login first. Make sure you have dockerhub account, then login from your machine by command:

```
docker login -u=your_dockerhub_username -p=your_dockerhub_password
```

Comment: It's not mandatory to have a dockerhub account to pull `node` image. If you look at the documentation [Test Docker installation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/#test-docker-installation), to pull `hello-world image` we are not logging in to access https://hub.docker.com/.  You need to login only to pull images from a private repository. [Refer here for more info](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/#private-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by ***ndoe:alpine***

1. if there is an image named as [ ***ndoe:alpine*** ] in your account. to pull that you must need to login to your hub account
2. otherwise it's just a typo **node:alpine**